# Slack Bot send DM message to the User

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to send message as DM to the users, so I've come with some questions;

1- There are two ways to send DM to the user;

- the first one open a conversation with user by using `conversation.open`, and send message. Then if I want to send the message to the same user, I use `conversation.list` and find the conversationId by userId, then send message to the same channel again.
- Second one is just basically using userId as channelId parameter in chatPostMessageRequest.

I've tried both ways, and both of them are sending message as DM. So, what is the purpose of using `conversation.open`? I'm asking this because nearly all the answers say you should do this etc.

2- Seems like there is no way to get multiple users by emails except `users.list`?

3- Also seems like there is no way to send messages to the multiple user at the same time (the content of the messages are different, those are depends on user data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a direct message by user ID *works* with `chat.postMessage` as a convenience, a shortcut. But it's the only method/API that allows you to use a user ID as a channel ID, so Slack warns developers away from relying on it in totality -- if you use `conversations.open` and the resultant conversation ID, it'll work for other methods like `chat.update` should you need to edit the message after sending it.

Slack doesn't offer many "lookup" APIs -- most things you'll want to look up require fetching an entire data set (like a list of users with all pages of `users.list`) and then filtering the results yourself. There are no APIs to look up multiple users at once via email address.

There is also no way to send the same direct message content to multiple users with a single request. In most cases, when an app is sending the same message to multiple users the best practice would be to use a channel to broadcast the message a single time, with the intended recipients as members of the channel.

Comment: It's better to use conversation instead of providing userId as channelId directly. Because it seems like it send messages via slackbot instead of opening a direct message with bot if we use userId directly. Thanks for your response about the all the answers!

Comment: I'm using conversations.open to get the channelID, and I pass this channelID to send a message via chat.postMessage(). However, I get an error saying 'user_not_found'. Any ideas what's wrong here?